# ng-repeat strange behaviour with boostrap modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i am trying to change the modal header and modal body text with the ng-repeat but the modal heading and data always point to the first array even though the the data is traversed in the anchor tag

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
  <td> <a ng-href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{x}}</a>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">{{x}}</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <p>{{x}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
  dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

the value of x

```
<td> <a ng-href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{x}}</a>
```

in anchor tag is according to the array showing all element but the value 
        of x in the below code

```
<h4 class="modal-title">{{x}}</h4>
```

and in the modal body always points to the first element of array

```
<p>{{x}}</p>
```

the value of X should change everywhere asper the array

Comment: Get rid of using bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with the modal `id` attribute, you have the same `id` for all modals, so when you try to open the modal, it will always open the same (first) one.

Use the `$index` variable inside the `id` attribute to make it unique:

```
<a ng-href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-{{$index}}">{{x}}</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-{{$index}}" role="dialog">
```